# Wamp is on but showing 404 Not Found not able to access any project

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

My wamp server is ON but it showing `404 Not Found` I am not able to access any project as well as phpmyadmin also. I am facing this problem first time how it comes and how to resolve it.

Skype is not on my system so it cant be that.

[image]

Comment: By right clicking on the wamp icon (bottom right on windows), you may be able to directly open your phpMyAdmin. Maybe it'll help you find the good root for this ;)

Comment: I have done this too but it not works

Comment: Does it work if you use `http://127.0.0.1` to get to localhost and `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` to get to phpMyAdmin? Also what version of WAMPServer did you install? Was it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I have tried http://127.0.0.1 http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/325115/f72fbc3e1d224cfe2a883e5a7ee37171 wamp server is 2.5. 32 bit

Comment: Did either of my suggested urls allow you to access phpmyadmin????

Comment: That screen shot is not anything that a standard Wampserver/Apache would look like, so what else have yo dont to WAMPServer after the basic install?? Or maybe you have another webserver running??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Open index.php in www folder and set

change this `$suppress_localhost = true;`

to `$suppress_localhost = false;`
```

> or Check whether any other application using your port(80)...
>
> [image: Restart]
>
> ust go to test `port 80`. If its being used by another process, you can
>   defined your own port at `httpd.conf` Search and find the following
>   string on file `httpd.conf1`

```
Listen 80
```

> and change to

```
Listen {to desired port like 8888}
```

**If the above method did not work try this**

> Try this solutions one by one.

**Solution 1:**

> If you using Windows 7, click the “show hidden icons buttons” in
>   taskbar right hand side. Left click WAMPSEVER icon.
>
> Go to Apache > Apache modules >. Scroll down mosule list. Find
>   “rewrite_module” and choose a tick mark. If you check this Wamp Server
>   automatically restarted. Now check your problem is solved.

**Solution 2:**

> Check your Wamp server icon in the task bar showing “green” or
>   “yellow” color. If it show green color, everything ok. but if it show
>   yellow color, you need to check all services are running correctly.
>
> Click Start button in your Windows OS. Type services.msc and press
>   enter button. Its open Services popup window. Scroll down and find
>   wampmysqld andwampapache services. If it status showing “started”,
>   everything ok. But its not show any status, right click and choose
>   start option.

Comment: Thanx 
I have changed port also but it not work it showing me Everything search bar please view attached screenshot http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/324837/92e3484e96cf467a7e495684923755dc

Comment: I have done both things you can screenshots but not working http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/325039/012ce7fa8929691275fbd8bc1347523b  http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/325044/9982b619d0b843e3c99d836ffa1c4e5b

Comment: [15-Jun-2015 07:46:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'I:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[15-Jun-2015 07:46:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'I:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The files are located in two places: `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin` and `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`. Putting the two in the apache folder into the Windows path didn't seem to work, then you  `php5.5.12` into the path and rebooted the server and that seemed to work. And if not works try this also To run `php_intl` you also have to copy the `icu*.dll` files from the php folder to the `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin` folder
And, You have to just needed to restart the server.

Comment: Yeah 3 month before i have installed wamp in (I directory) and uninstalled wamp from C might it be causing problem. I have wamp folder in C drive and i have deleted it now 
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Mon Jun 15 15:08:41.864231 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2392:tid 316] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jun 15 15:09:41.734655 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3412:tid 392] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.

Comment: Then use:- Using the wampmanager menus do **`wampmanager -> Apache -> Version `** and click on the version number probably it will be 2.4.9 and this will rebuild all the **SYMLINKS** in the `apache/bin` folder and` Apache/PHP` will be able to find the **dll's** required for these 2 extensions. And Finally if not solved try to backup data and uninstall and install freshly..